# Angular ng-repeat orderBy forllowing a specific schema

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, angularjs-ng-repeat, alphabetical

I have the following code:

```
<td>
   <div ng-repeat="authority in user.authorities">
       <span class="label label-info">{{ authority }}</span>
   </div>
</td>
```

And in my javascript, user.authorities can be defined like this:

```
vm.authorities = ['ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_INVITE', 'ROLE_SuperADMIN'];
```

Everything is OK but the result is

ROLE_ADMIN

ROLE_INVITE

ROLE_SuperADMIN

ROLE_USER

And I would like to obtain:

ROLE_INVITE

ROLE_USER

ROLE_ADMIN

ROLE_SuperADMIN

ie a non alphabetical order... I searched over stackoverflow a solution but did not found it...

Could you tell me how I could do? I would not like to change the definition of my object...

Answer (score 1):

You should add a field to order your list, i.e.:

```
vm.authorities = [{order: 1, name: 'ROLE_USER'}, ...];
```

and use `| orderBy:'order'` in your `ng-repeat`

(Sorry, now I've read all the question carefully)

And in case you don't want to change your array, you can create a custom compare method. More info here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy